# special character in function argument within Shiny app

Tags: r, function, shiny, arguments

Inside the UI part of a Shiny app i have the following:

```
sliderInput("cvn","Enter the cv training n number:",min = 1,
                            max = 20,
                            value = cvnumber,step = 1)
```

Then within the server part of the same shiny app i want to call a function and pass the `input$cvn` as an argument as in the following lines:

```
funcfit_cart <- function( input$cvn ){
        set.seed(123)
        fit.cart <- train(as.formula(paste(input$var ,  " ~ .")),
        data = gyno_train(), method="rpart", metric=metric, trControl=trainControl(method="cv", number=cvnumber))
        return(fit.cart)
    }
```

As i try to do this i get the red x error flag message:

```
unexpected token 'input', expected 'RPAREN'
unexpected closing bracket 'input'
unmatched opening bracket '('
missing function definition
unexpected token '$'
unexpected token ')'
```

Do you know how i can insert within the function argument the call to the `input$cvn` ?

Comment: There's a missing `)` in `fit.cart <-`.

Comment: i checked again but it still does not work, i think the problem may have to do with the special character "$" inside the argument. Do you know how i can solve it ?

Comment: Indeed, `function( input$cvn ){` is wrong.

Comment: what would be the solution ? how can i get `input$cvn` inside the argument of the function without getting an error ?

Comment: `funcfit_cart <- function( x ){ ......` and run `funcfit_cart(input$cvn)`. I have the impression you have to learn the basics of R.